# Using valgrind to profile the whole machine?

Tags: valgrind

I would like to use valgrind (http://valgrind.org) to profile the whole system instead of just the command provided.

From the documentation:

> valgrind --leak-check=yes myprog arg1 arg2

I want to provide sleep 100 for example for myprog and arg1 so that it can collect data for 100 seconds.

Comment: What do you mean by the 'whole system'? Would that include other processes and kernel activity that may be unrelated to your app? If so you probably want to look at something like `perf` https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/developer_guide/perf

Comment: I would like to use the itrace tool to collect scroll pipe data on the entire machine including other processes and kernel activity

Comment: OK, so Valgrind isn't the answer. It will only trace app + system calls, nothing outside of the process.

Comment: Thank you. I will keep looking for other trace tools